# Starting Activity in AsyncTask passing context from activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask, android-context

Here is the AsyncTask constructor:

```
private Context context;
private MainActivity activity;
public databaseTask(MainActivity activity, String task, String username, String password) {
    super();
    this.activity = activity;
    this.context = this.activity.getApplicationContext();
```

And here is the call in MainActivity:

```
databaseTask dbGetGroupsTask = new databaseTask(MainActivity.this, "login", username, password);
dbGetGroupsTask.execute(username);
```

In the onPostExecute I have this code:

```
Intent s = new Intent(context, userLandingPage.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("userName", username);
s.putExtras(b);
context.startActivity(s);
```

The error I am getting at runtime is: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

From all the replies in previous questions I have seen it says in order to start an activity from outside the activity without setting a flag (as setting the flag is not recommended) you need to have the context of the activity. I thought this was what I was doing so I am not sure why this not working.

Comment: try with activity.startActivity(s);

Comment: `Intent s = new Intent(activity, userLandingPage.class);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since one of the argument of your AsyncTask is the activity you can directly use

```
Intent s = new Intent(activity, userLandingPage.class);
activity.startActivity(s);
```

Comment: right he is, don't start an activity from the application context, it's not meant for that... and if you do indeed you create a  new task, unless your activity ins a single task activity in which i'm not sure the behavior is even defined...

Comment: I just tried running that as well, I am still getting the same runtime error about calling startActivity() from outside an Activity context.

Comment: use  activity to start the new activity. Are you running it inside onPostExecute?

Comment: I just did that as well, thank you that worked. I tried changing the startActivity call to every way I could think of but had not changed the intent along with it.